# Given two sets, how can I determine what was added or removed?

Tags: swift, algorithm, sorting

```
let first =  { 2, 4, 5, 9 };
let second = { 2, 8, 15, 53, 4 }

//removed = 5, 9
//added = 8, 15, 53
```

What is the simplest solution to determine what was added or removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use set differences.

To determine what was added, take the set subtraction

```
second.subtracting(first)
```

To determine what was removed, take

```
first.subtracting(second)
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple algorithm for determining the changes is similar to the [merge algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm) for sorted lists:

- Order both sets
- Start iterating both ordered lists at the initial element
- In a loop, if the current item from both lists is the same, skip it by moving to the next element of both lists
- If the item in the original set is smaller, add it to the list of removed items, and move the original set to the next item
- If the item in the new set is smaller, add it to the list of added items, and move the new set to the next item
- If you reach the end of one of two lists before the other one, add the remaining elements to the corresponding output list (added or removed).

Comment: What do you think of using the `.subtract` method?

Comment: @TIMEX set subtraction would probably work pretty well, too.